# nftables alternative for iptables -F

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, nftables

Simply, is there any quick alternative of `iptables -F` command (that just "deletes everything") for nftables?

Such thing wouldn't have much theoretical purposes, but it's usually a lifesaver for administration of bad/gone-wrong setups.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are looking for `nft flush` commmand. The syntax is:

```
$ nft flush table <name>
```

You can also flush chain:

```
$ nft flush chain <table> <name>
```

Alternatively you can always use `nft delete rule` command to delete any rules that you have just applied.

Answer (score 2):

To flush the entire ruleset, including all tables and chains in one go.

```
$ nft flush ruleset
```

Comment: Welcome to Serverfault! We have two kind of citation methods. The one starting with `>` is for text quotes. By indenting the text with four spaces you can add a code block. I edited this for you.